# Saving R plot_ly graphs in pdf format

Tags: r, r-plotly

I've been using plot_ly to generate 3d scatterplots. I would like to be able to save the graphs in pdf (or other image format) as I do with plot in R, but when I attempt the following:

```
pdf(file = "Alpha_Beta_Gamma.pdf")
plot_ly = (x=pm$theta, y=pm$alpha, z=pm$Gamma, type="scatter3d")
dev.off()
```

a blank pdf file is returned. Note that the plot_ly command on its own works fine except for a warning message about no mode being specified, and generates an html 3d scatterplot.

Comment: This isn't legal R code (`(x=pm$theta,...)`). I can infer what you might be doing, but it's better to be certain. Can you correct your code, please?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using  `pdf(...)`? Have a look at `export` from the `plotly` package.

Comment: pm is a dataframe, with theta, alpha, gamma column names. The syntax that I posted for plot_ly works - insofar as it generates a figure, I just can't save it as a pdf

Comment: I would prefer pdf output, but it isn't mandatory. The only thing I found for exporting images in plotly is using an external program (orca). https://plotly.com/r/static-image-export/ Is there an argument internal to plotly that will allow me to do the same?

Comment: as a fast work around if your using RStudio: open the plot in a browers and press "strg+ p"